# Akka typed sending messages during spawning

Tags: java, spring, akka, akka-actor, akka-typed

The question is fairly self explanatory.

Currently my webapp is creating the actor system in startup, and spawning some top level actors using `SpawnProtocol`. Additionally the startup could also send some messages to these actors during start up.

When creating the top level actors, akka returns a `CompletionStage` that waits for the actor to be created.

What is the best design pattern for this scenario of accepting messages during the spawning of the actor? Should I make the start up wait for the actor spawning to complete, or stash the messages sent and let the thread continue? If stashing then please send some example stashing techniques that are thread safe and performant

Note that I am using akka-typed, java and spring within my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea would be to use `CompletionStage` API to chain calls to bootstrap your app.

```java
CompletionStage<ActorRef<Stuff>> actorRefPromise = spawnActorRef();

actorRefPromise.thenApply(actorRef -> bootStrapApp(actorRef))
```

Since you weren't too specific about your bootstrapping I am assuming that you need one `ActorRef` to bootstrap you app. In the above snippet `spawnActorRef()` is what calls the `SpawnProtocol` and returns `CompletionStage` of your `ActorRef` you can then use `thenApply` to chain an action once that ref is available and use that to pass to the rest of your bootstrapping code.

Comment: I am using a spring webapp on a tomcat server. the spring application creates the actorSystem and then individual spring beans create the actors using SpawnProtocol.

What I am looking for is a way for the individual spring bean actors to receive messages and cache them to be sent when the actorRef future completes.

Comment: Where do those Spring beans get the messages from to cache? From web call? Are they services? Does it happen during http request processing?

Comment: Scheduled triggers from within the application is the key part I'm interested in. But they are also triggered from web calls

Comment: how about calling `spawnActorRef().toCompletableFuture().join()` to block the actor creation and then just pass the message to it?

Comment: Yes that works too. I was asking for what the best design pattern would be? I'm not too keen on putting blocks into the application, but had not found another way

Comment: So the theme here is asynchornicity. Akka throws you into asynchronous world by returning you a `CompletionStage`. If you are using Spring's Webflux stack, which is also async, then you could start your request processing by `Mono.fromCompletionStage(spawnActorRef())` and then keep on going using `Mono`'s API to process your request. You could leverage that same API in your scheduled jobs, or you could just use the `CompletionStage` API which is a bit more clunky IMO, but would still work.

Comment: thank you. So I have written it now as a `CompletionStage` builder where each `actorRef::tell` message is adding another `CompletionStage::thenApply` to the chain. This looks to have worked. I will look more into Mono's API as I have not seen that before.